# Crash in wcscpy_s

Tags: c, struct

I am getting crash in `wcscpy`_s while `wcscpy` works fine. I have the following struct

```
struct Test {
...
wchar_t         identity[256 * 2];  
...
};
```

I am doing member-by-member copy of one struct into another. The below one is crashing

```
wcscpy_s(t2.identity, sizeof(t2.identity) , t1.identity);
```

while this one is working fine:

```
wcscpy(t2.identity, t1.identity);
```

Comment: Note that you have declared `identity` to have room for 512 wide characters. `sizeof(t2.identity)` will return 1024 bytes (each `wchar_t` is 2 bytes in Windows). The second parameter in wcscpy_s should be `sizeof(t2.identity)/sizeof(wchar_t)` or use `_countof` as suggested in the answer, this will give 512.

Answer (score 5):

If you [read the `wcscpy_s` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) you will see that the middle argument is the number of ***elements***, while you pass the size of the array ***in bytes***.

If you're using Visual C++ then you can use e.g. [`_countof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx) to get the number of elements.

Comment: Hmmm, This answer has correct information, yet it does _not_ explain OP's problem unless `t1.identity` lacks a terminator or was from some other `struct` with a larger `identity[]` field.  UV for detailing correct coding.